# Compiling C program on Mac results in `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` error

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I am trying to compile a C program on my MacBook Pro, so far the files I have look something like this:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "blah.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    //do stuff
    return 0;
}
```

**blah.h**

```
extern void method1()
extern void method2()
extern void method3()
```

**blah.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "blah.h"

void method1()
{
    //do stuff
}

void method2()
{
    //do stuff
}

void method3()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

However, when I try to compile, I get an error like:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_method1", referenced from:
      _main in ccVPIYad.o
  "_method2", referenced from:
      _main in ccVPIYad.o
  "_method3", referenced from:
      _main in ccVPIYad.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think this is because Mac compiler adds an underscore in front of every function name, but I'm not sure how to fix this. I've tried changing `blah.h` to this:

```
extern void method1() asm ("create_list");
extern void method2() asm ("print");
extern void method3() asm ("insert_front");
```

but it is not fixing the problem.

Comment: Remove `extern` from the functions declarations.

Comment: You need to include `blah.c` in your compile command.

Comment: Essentially the same problem with an answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019908/gcc-4-2-1-linking-issue-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64

Comment: 1. Functions do not need an `extern` keyword.  

2. You forgot commas in your blah.h file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual function definitions are in another source file which you are not compiling with.

Do:

```
 gcc blah.c main.c -o main
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What @[l3x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275169/l3x) [wrote](/a/34844269/2599567)
2. Remove `extern` and add semicolons

Updated `blah.h`:

```
void method1();
void method2();
void method3();
```